# Is there a way to use images on web directly in TagEditor?

Tags: powershell, command-line, media

I am using [TagEditor Project](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor) to add a custom thumbnail to a video.
The syntax is-

```
tageditor -s cover=image.png -f video.mp4
```

This works perfectly but only if the image is locally saved.
For some image on the internet, it does not work

```
tageditor -s cover='https://abcd.ef/image.png' -f video.mp4     # This does not work
```

I can make a script to download the images and then delete them but that would be inefficient (I guess)

Is there a way this can be done more efficiently/directly?

*not sure if stackOverflow is the right place for this or the project's GitHub issues so please forgive me if it does not belong here*

Comment: guys please tell me if it's not possible

Comment: That's probably not possible but you could always ask the [creator](https://github.com/Martchus) if that feature can be built in with following releases.